# COM interop and System.InvalidCastException exception

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop

I’m new to writing COM objects in C#. I am running into an issue that I need help with.

I have a COM interface written in C++ called ITest. I created an interop for the DLL that this interface is present in using tlbimp.exe and registered it on my test system. I wrote a C# test application that uses this ITest interface, and it is working fine.

I am also writing another COM interface in C#. This interface has a method which takes an argument of type ITest. I have a C++ program that needs to use this managed COM object and call this method. When I run my C++ program, I am seeing the following System.InvalidCastException exception:

```
InvalidCastException:
0:000> !pe
Exception object: 03281b3c
Exception type:   System.InvalidCastException
Message:          Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type '.ITest'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '<Some GUID>' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
InnerException:   <none>
StackTrace (generated): <none>
StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80004002
```

C# COM interface’s method definition:

```
public void MyMethod(ITest pTest);
```

C++ code that uses this COM interface:

```
ITest * pTest = NULL;
…
pTest gets assigned a valid pointer
…
hr = MyMethod(pTest);
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction and help me debug this problem?

Comment: You'll need to debug your implementation of IUnknown::QueryInterface().